# Matching specific indices of columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the following code (it is part of the code) where I am adding crosses in specific positions to several images. I get the coordinates of the positions for each image from a CSV file. I wrote a code but it adds all the positions on all images. I want to add the marks that represent the positions that correspond to their image. Could you help?

```
import pandas as pd
from osgeo import gdal  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os
import glob


for image in target_data['Region']:
    images_path = os.path.join('path',str(image)+'*.TIF')
    full_name = (glob.glob(images_path))
    if full_name == []:
        print( image + ' does not match any region in the specified path')
    else:
        print(full_name[0])
        print(type(full_name[0]))
        img =  gdal.Open(full_name[0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
        rb = img.GetRasterBand(1)
        img_array = rb.ReadAsArray())
        imgplot = plt.imshow(img_array)
        plt.imshow(img_array) # plot image
        x = target_data['X'] # X is a column in the CSV file that has all the X_coordinates
        y = target_data['Y'] #Y is a column in the CSV file that has all the Y_coordinates
        size = 50 # size of marker
        plt.scatter(x, y, size, c="r", marker="+") # plot markers
        plt.show()
```

You can find a sample of the data in this link. I am not sure if I can share an image from my data, so it would be appreciated if you try it on any image online.

https://easyupload.io/vlpkl7

The column 'Region' represents the images' names in my folder

Comment: Hi @Mohammed Zidane. Welcome to SO. Share a sample of your data so we may test potential solutions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I edited the question, you can find a sample.